# Debugging an SBCL User-Defined Hash-table Test

Tags: common-lisp, hashtable, hashcode, sbcl

I'm having trouble understanding an SBCL 2.3.2 error message involving a user-defined hash-table test. Also, is there a better/faster way to implement this?

```
debugger invoked on a TYPE-ERROR @2226541F in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {23500049}>:
  The value
    615700690
  is not of type
    FIXNUM
  when binding SB-IMPL::HASH0

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [ABORT] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

(SB-IMPL::PUTHASH/ANY #<unavailable argument> #<unavailable argument> #<unavailable argument>)
0]
```

The relevant definitions, which all compile successfully, include:

```
(sb-ext:define-hash-table-test state-equal-p state-equal-p-hash)

(defun state-equal-p (state1 state2)
  (declare (problem-state state1 state2))
  (equalp (problem-state.idb state1) (problem-state.idb state2)))

(defun state-equal-p-hash (state)
  (declare (problem-state state))
  (let ((sum 0))
    (maphash (lambda (key value)  ;keys are type integer
               (declare (ignore value))
               (incf sum key))
      (problem-state.idb state))
    sum))
```

Comment: The issue seems to do with different versions of SBCL. Version 2.3.1 allows most-positive-fixnum = 4611686018427387903, while version 2.3.2 allows 536870911. But why are these different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a 32-bit version of SBCL, and `most-positive-fixnum` is 2^29 - 1.  So you've probably downloaded a 32-bit version of SBCL by mistake.

However nothing in your hash function tries to be sure that it returns a non-negative fixnum, which it must do.  So you were just lucky that you never overflowed the fixnum limit in 64-bit SBCL previously.